# Почему не могу войти в админку EasyAdmin на Symfony?

Tags: symfony

Всем привет. Изучаю симфони 6 и решил на свой небольшой учебный бложек накатить админку . Установил по документации EasyAdmin и дошел ровно до момента когда написал следущее

```
$adminUrlGenerator = $this->container->get(AdminUrlGenerator::class);
return $this->redirect($adminUrlGenerator->setController(UserCrudController::class)->generateUrl());
```

Судя по документации после этих действий должна была открыться приятная картинка с CRUD'ом для пользователей, но увидел я вот это

```
An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Пишет что соединение плохое, хотя я по 127.0.0.1:5432 соединяюсь с бд через воркбенч, все работает. Может где конфиг админки поправить нужно?

Comment: Какое окружение используется (openserver, docker или другое)?